# Not able to launch RIDE with ride.py

Tags: python, robotframework-ide

On running pip install -U robotframework-ride

`Requirement already satisfied: robotframework-ride in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (2.0.5)`
`Requirement already satisfied: PyPubSub in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from robotframework-ride) (4.0.3)`
`Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from robotframework-ride) (2.15.1)`
`Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from robotframework-ride) (5.9.5)`
`Requirement already satisfied: wxPython in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from robotframework-ride) (4.2.0)`
`Requirement already satisfied: Pywin32 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from robotframework-ride) (306)`
`Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from wxPython->robotframework-ride) (9.5.0)`
`Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from wxPython->robotframework-ride) (1.16.0)`
`Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from wxPython->robotframework-ride) (1.24.3)`

but when I run command ride.py it says:-

`wxPython not found. RIDE depends on wx (wxPython). Historically, the last supported version was 2.8.12.1 with unicode support.At the time of this release the current wxPython version is 4.0.7.post2.You can install with 'pip install wxPython' on most operating systems, or find the the download link from https://wxPython.org/`

Python version:- Python 3.11.3

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: The installer is broken; the code has a certain expectation for the highest version of wxPython that it will accept, but the installer will install (or accept if it is already there) whatever most recent version. More to the point, it appears that this program *does not support your Python version* (it is too new). This is something that you should address using the project's issue tracker isntead.

Comment: Okay. Let me downgrade python and try once.